# Slow rendering speed of {{> yield}}

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm currently building a mobile check in app using built in cordova commands on meteor, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out why loading a certain template is taking between 1 to 2 seconds to load.

I have a layout that has a fixed header, and a tabs bar at the bottom that has 4 icons that you can navigate using (kind of like Instagram's tab bar). Everything else comes in through yield.

The problem is that the main home page that has the list of posts collection gradually begins to take longer to load when I click the home tab from anywhere else. I have infinite scrolling implemented, so at most 10 post collections are shown when a user taps home. The yield render speed is incredibly slower if the home page has 10 posts compared to 0. Is there any way to solve this issue?

I'm currently using iron router and publishing only the posts that the user owns and their friends' posts. I don't think it's a pub sub issue because even if I have 100 posts in the db that the user is subscribing to, the homepage will just be faster if I limit the infinite scroll to show only 5 posts at the beginning compared to 10.

Can this be a client side issue? I'm googling as much as possible for a solution but people are talking about slow render speeds for displaying 2000 documents, etc. I'm just talking about 5 or 10 documents.

Edit (thanks to user ghybs):

The infinite scrolling was implement by using a "limit" Session variable that tracks how many number of documents it should display. It starts at 10, and increments by 10. I'm currently using blaze to loop through all the subscribed Post documents by using {{posts}} and having posts as a template helper that returns posts.find({},{limit:limitvar}) with the limitvar being the session variable that starts at 10. I also do have to mention that the session variable is a global one so that when the user comes back to the main homepage tab, all the loaded posts are still present and does not reset at 10 until the app is restarted or if the page is refreshed (however, difficult to refresh the page since its a cordova mobile app).

No matter how many documents the user has subscribed too, displaying 10 documents has the exact same render time with someone who has only subscribed to 10 documents. I'm also using Kadira to track my performance, and there is nothing out of the ordinary (everything under 150ms).

To explain what I mean by "taking long to load": When the user taps the home button on the tab bar at the bottom of the page, the app just freezes for a second or two and then directs the user to the main page. If there are a few posts (or none), the freeze time is lower (and unnoticeable with 0 docs). I have set a loading template in my router.js. If this was anything related to pub/sub or the server, it would display a spinner indicating that the page is loading.

Currently I'm trying my hardest to change things little by little to make the page load faster by getting rid of as many mongodb "find" methods within my js client files. Not sure if this is the best way to handle things. I'm also thinking about moving over to flowrouter from ironrouter, though I am still not so sure if this will fix the load time for the main page, as these are simply just routers.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since you suspect a client side issue related with your infinite scrolling, it would be worth sharing how you implemented it / your client code. Otherwise, people will just answer with wild guess.

Comment: Yes, please show the js code for the template that is being put into the yield. That's where things are most likely to be slow.